# The ngNonBindable directive not working properly in the case of attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The `ngNonBindable` should ignore the content of the current DOM element but it looks like in some circumstances it does not.

Let's take a look at the example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <div title="{{1 + 2}}">Test 1 - See title</div>
  <div ng-non-bindable title="Ignored: {{1 + 2}}">Test 2 - See title</div>
  <!-- Uncomment following line and check JS console: -->
  <!-- <div ng-non-bindable title="Is it really ignored: {{invalid expression}}">Test 3 - See title</div> -->

</body>
```

The code above works as expected:

- In the case of `Test 1` - the title attribute is set to `3`
- In the case of `Test 2` - the title attribute is ignored and hence set to `Ignored {{1 + 2}}`

Now comes interesting part - if you try to uncomment commented code and run it, this exception will be thrown:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$parse/syntax?p0=test&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=6&p3=test%20test&p4=test
at Error (native)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:6:449
at Ya.throwError (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:155:141)
at Ya.parse (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:154:6)
at $get (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:91:203)
at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:73:117)
at S (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:57:109)
at J (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:44:286)
at N (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:42:489)
at N (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:43:145)
```

I would expect `Test 3` to have title set to `Is it really ignored: {{invalid expression}}` which is not a case. So to me it looks like only valid expressions are ignored which doesn't make much sense. Is this a bug - or am I missing something? Do you have any idea of how to circumvent this?